# Tracing a PHPUnit Error

Tags: php, laravel-4, phpunit

I'm having issues finding the source of an error I'm receiving in PHPUnit. If I run phpunit with no filter I will receive the "bytes exhausted" error.
however if I run my tests one at a time with phpunit --filter test_name - all of my test will pass.

The stack trace posted below indicates a problem with one of my tests called KInit however if run that test by itself everything passes.
I have also tried to move the test out of the directory but the error will simply point to the next test that is run. I have also tried running with sudo which did not work any better.
How can I get more information on whats happening here?

I'm running PHPUint to test a laravel 4.2 app.
versions of stuff
PHPUnit 4.1.4 
PHP 5.5.18
Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit

The stack trace below says the error is in:

```
laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php
```

however sometimes it reads

```
/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/CacheServiceProvider.php
```

Full stack trace:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 15886 bytes) in /opt/pplus/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php on line 31
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /usr/local/bin/phpunit:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /usr/local/bin/phpunit:586
PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:132
PHP   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:179
PHP   5. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/TestRunner.php:426
PHP   6. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestSuite.php:675
PHP   7. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestSuite.php:675
PHP   8. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestSuite.php:675
PHP   9. PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php:758
PHP  10. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runBare() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestResult.php:686
PHP  11. KInitTest->setUp() phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php:818
PHP  12. TestCase->setUp() /opt/pplus/laravel/app/tests/unit/classes/KInit/KInitTest.php:16
PHP  13. Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase->setUp() /opt/pplus/laravel/app/tests/TestCase.php:35
PHP  14. Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase->refreshApplication() /opt/pplus/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.php:31
PHP  15. TestCase->createApplication() /opt/pplus/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.php:42
PHP  16. require() /opt/pplus/laravel/app/tests/TestCase.php:17
PHP  17. require() /opt/pplus/laravel/bootstrap/start.php:60
PHP  18. Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository->load() /opt/pplus/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/start.php:210
PHP  19. Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository->loadManifest() /opt/pplus/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php:51
PHP  20. Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem->get() /opt/pplus/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php:187
PHP  21. file_get_contents() /opt/pplus/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:31
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. I had to increase the memory_limit in /etc/php5/cli/php.ini. I always forget the phpunit uses a different ini file than apache.